# Ambiguity of type during initialization

Tags: rust

I've come across an interesting situation where Rust can't properly deduce the type of a value during initialization even if it is specified. Let's start with examples:

This is ok:

```
let level: log::LogLevelFilter = {
    let mut level = log::LogLevelFilter::Debug;
    if env::var("TRACE_ENABLED").is_ok() {
        level = log::LogLevelFilter::Trace;
    }
    level
};
```

This is not:

```
let level: log::LogLevelFilter = {
    if env::var("TRACE_ENABLED").is_ok() {
        return log::LogLevelFilter::Trace
    }
    log::LogLevelFilter::Debug
};
```

Error text:

```
src/main.rs:26:20: 26:46 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `log::LogLevelFilter`
(expected (),
    found enum `log::LogLevelFilter`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:26             return log::LogLevelFilter::Trace
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:26:20: 26:46 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
```

What is wrong here? I think I've written code like this before without any problem.

[Shorter example with similar problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e24219cbb9c78e2ce63d9da5e0c0e30e&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: `return log::LogLevelFilter::Trace` means you return from the current function. So the function's return type must match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `return` here is trying to return that value from the function that you're in (not the curly brace block), and that function expects a return value of type `()`, which is what the error message says.

A more idiomatic way to write this would be:

```
let level: log::LogLevelFilter = if env::var("TRACE_ENABLED").is_ok() {
    log::LogLevelFilter::Trace
} else {
    log::LogLevelFilter::Debug
};
```

and you most likely don't even need the `level: log::LogLevelFilter` type annotation.

Comment: Could even end up with `let level = env::var("TRACE_ENABLED").ok().map_or(LogLevelFilter::Debug, |_| LogLevelFilter::Trace);`

Comment: I think the outer block isn't necessary, [`let level = if env::var("TRACE_ENABLED").is_ok() { log::LogLevelFilter::Trace } else { log::LogLevelFilter::Debug };`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=enum%20LogLevel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Trace%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Debug%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20cond%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20level%20%3D%20if%20cond%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LogLevel%3A%3ATrace%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LogLevel%3A%3ADebug%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) is enough.

Comment: @Shepmaster that looks a bit too cryptic in my opinion, but it's a valid shorter solution :)

Comment: @Kroltan you're right, thanks! I've updated my code.